# How do I select a name from a list on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, save

More help with my banking ATM school project. The problem is that I have created a program that lets the users enter a name into a save elsewhere, but I cant select a name from that save to use again. This is my code.

```
f1 =open('C:\NameAgeFile', 'r')
filedata = f1.read()
f1.close()

print filedata
```

This prints a list of all the registered users on the shell, but how can I make it so that if the user wants to log back in, say under the name "Michael" on the list, and then retrieve the bank balance for that user?

```
balance_user = 500
f1 =open('N:\userFile', 'r')
filedata = f1.read()
f1.close()

print filedata
print "Welcome to the Banking Bank PLC public ATM service"
print "If you do have an account allready, select your name from the list of registered users."
user = raw_input("Please enter your ATM account name and insert your Banking Card. If you do not have an ATM account, please insert your Banking Card and enter New_User.")
if user == "New_User":
    print "Weclome to the Banking Bank PLC ATM service."
    user = raw_input ("Please enter an ATM account name that you wish to use to log onto the Banking Bank ATMs")

    f1 =open('N:\userFile', 'a+')
    print >> f1,user


print "Welcome", user, "to the Banking Bank PLC ATM service."
print "You have been given £100 for signing up. Please log out and back on to bank."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names in you **filedata** variable seems to be separated by new lines, so you can split it by **'\n'** character and put it to a list.

From there you can check whether the user entered name is in the list or not.

```
name_list = filedata.split('\n')

if user in name_list:
    #your login code
```

Answer (score 2):

A more pythonic way to read the file will be by using a `with` scope and using the readlines() method:

```
path = 'N:\users_file'
username = 'some_username'

# Open the file
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    # Iterate over the lines in the file
    for user in file.readlines():
        if user == username:
            # Do something
```